# How can I show a Visibility widget based on multiple conditions?

Tags: flutter, visibility

I'm building a restaurant menu app and one of the features of the menu is to allow the users to pick their allergies so the app will turn the menu items containing those allergenics unclickable.

```
bool allergies = false;
```

```
Visibility(
    visible: allergies,
    child: Plate_Widget())
```

Some plates, turns out can have multiple allergenics so I need a way to set multiple booleans per each widget.
If I set multiple bools or a list of bools flutter says:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

To show a `Visibility` widget based on *multiple* conditions, you can create your own widget that accepts a list of `bool`s:

```
class CustomVisibility extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<bool> conditions;
  final Widget child;

  const CustomVisibility(
      {required this.conditions, required this.child, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
    // returns true if all `conditions` are true, returns false otherwise
      visible: conditions.every((element) => element),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can call it as follows:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final isVisible = true;
  final condition2 = true;
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomVisibility(
        conditions: [isVisible, condition2], child: const Text('Hello'));
  }
}
```

---

Here's a complete runnable snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final isVisible = true;
  final condition2 = true;
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomVisibility(
        conditions: [isVisible, condition2], child: const Text('Hello'));
  }
}

class CustomVisibility extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<bool> conditions;
  final Widget child;

  const CustomVisibility(
      {required this.conditions, required this.child, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      // if all conditions are true, then show the child
      visible: conditions.every((element) => element),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```